# Proof for intersection of right cosets being the empty set

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> Either $Hg = Hb$ $\vee$ $Hg \cap Hb \neq\varnothing $

Assume to the contrary that $Hg\cap Hb\neq \varnothing $

Then, $x = hg \exists h \in H \wedge x=hb\exists h\in H$

so, $x=hg =hb$

Recall that:

> $Hg=H$ IF and Only If $g\in H$

Indeed, $g\in H$ (can be proven)

$Hx=\left ( Hh \right )g=Hg \subset H$

$Hx=\left ( Hh \right )b=Hb\subset H$

Therefore, $Hg=Hb$

I was given an alternative proof but wonder if this is equally valid.

Comment: Or you can show that the defining relation $\sim$ is an equivalence relation: $x\in G\sim y\in G\Leftrightarrow xy^{-1}\in H$

Comment: $x = hg$ for some $h \in H$, and $x = hb$ for some $h \in H$, but not necessarily the same $h$, so you cannot conclude that $hg = hb$.

Answer (score 0):

It is usually NOT true that $Hx = H$ ($x$ may not lie in $H$).

You'd want to proceed like this:

Suppose $x = h_1g = h_2b$.

Let $z$ be any element of $Hg$. Then $z = hg$ (we don't know which $h \in H$, it turns out it doesn't matter, all we will use is that it lies in $H$).

Now $h_1h^{-1}z = h_1h^{-1}(hg) = h_1g = h_2b$.

It therefore follows that $z = (hh_1^{-1})(h_1h^{-1}z) = (hh_1^{-1})(h_2b) = (hh_1^{-1}h_2)b$.

Since $hh_1^{-1}h_2 \in H$ by closure, $z \in Hb$, and thus $Hg \subseteq Hb$.

A similar argument (which I leave to you) shows $Hb \subseteq Hg$, which will then prove the equality.